# Grails validation dependent on related domains

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, jqgrid, dependencies

I have several domain classes that are related and I am trying to figure out how to implement a constraint that depends on multiple domains.  The jist of the problem is:

Asset has many Capacity pool objects

Asset has many Resource objects

When I create/edit a resource, need to check that total resources for an Asset doesn't exceed Capacity.

I created a service method that accomplishes this, but shouldn't this be done via a validator in the Resource domain?  My service class as listed below:

```
    def checkCapacityAllocation(Asset asset, VirtualResource newItem) {     

// Get total Resources allocated from "asset"
        def allAllocated = Resource.createCriteria().list() {
            like("asset", asset)
        }
        def allocArray = allAllocated.toArray()
        def allocTotal=0.0
        for (def i=0; i<allocArray.length; i++) {
            allocTotal = allocTotal.plus(allocArray[i].resourceAllocated)
        }


// Get total capacities for "asset"
        def allCapacities = AssetCapacity.createCriteria().list() {
            like("asset", asset)

        }
        def capacityArray = allCapacities.toArray()
        def capacityTotal = 0.0
        for (def i=0; i<capacityArray.length; i++) {
            capacityTotal += capacityArray[i].actualAvailableCapacity
        }

        if (allocTotal > capacityTotal) {
           return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The problem I am having is using this method for validation.  I am using the JqGrid plugin (with inline editing) and error reporting is problematic.  If I could do this type of validation in the domain it would make things a lot easier.  Any suggestions?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the service method as a validator, you'll need to inject the service into your domain, then add a custom validator that calls it. I think it'll look something like this:

```
class Asset {

    def assetService

    static hasMany = [resources: Resource]

    static constraints = {
        resources(validator: { val, obj ->
            obj.assetService.checkCapacityAllocation(obj, val)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Great it worked! Now I just gotta get the inline "action" formatter with jqgrid to work correctly with constraints...  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def resourceCount = Resource.countByAsset(assetId)
def assetCapacityCount = AssetCapacity.countByAsset(assetId)
if(resourceCount < assetCapacityCount) return true
return false
```

HTH

Comment: That's a nice way of making the method shorter, but I'm still not sure how to use it as a constraint to be checked when editing/adding rows

Comment: You can add the code I wrote above into a custom validator mentioned by @doelleri.